# Random Not Found</h1><p>The requested resource was not found on this server.</p>

Tags: django, gunicorn

I'm experiencing an issue which seems to be related somehow to Gunicorn + Django and I can't find the cause of the problem.

I start Gunicorn using this command:

`python manage.py collectstatic --clear --noinput & gunicorn config.wsgi --bind=0.0.0.0:5000 --timeout=300 --workers=2 --threads=4 --worker-class=gthread --name=api --log-level debug --error-logfile gunicorn_error.log --access-logfile - --capture-output`

and then while trying to curl for example CSS file :

`curl http://0.0.0.0:5000/STATIC_DIR/CSS/FILE.css?v23423424`

sometimes I get the correct response and CSS file but sometimes:

`<h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested resource was not found on this server.</p>`

interestingly, if, for example, I kill 2 of the 3 gunicorn processes, they will start again in a moment and then everything will work properly. I can't find anything in the logs which can indicate the reason.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

- enable DEBUG log
- try different types of worker-class

Comment: Did you collectstatic files by running `python manage.py collectstatic` ? Also make sure to restart gunicorn after this.

Comment: @MohammadGolamDostogir yes, I've just updated the command I use: python manage.py collectstatic is included

Comment: Did it work? Also try restart gunicorn service.

Comment: Unfortunately I doesn't work. Restarting is no an option cause I run it as k8s pod. If I restart gunicorn, the whole pod will be restarted and the issue persists.